# R, please Check my longest Drawdowns function

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I can't get performanceAnalytics to work with my zoo series and I've decided to write my own script.

It's supposed to get  cummax(equity)-equity  as input if you want to calculate de longest Drawdowns. It also gives the max drawdown value on these periods.

corrected version is below.

Please, Could you check my script. It doesn't work as expected. Some maxDD are zero.
I hope it can be useful to other people. I've seen many messages at forums where people looks for something like this.

I've corrected it with Richie suggestions:

```
  findDD <- function(DD, n=5){
  rr <- rle(sign(coredata(DD)))
  lens <- rr$length
  lens[!rr$value] <- 0
  ll <- head(order(lens, decreasing=TRUE),n)
  sumas <- cumsum(c(1,rr$length)) # I need to access the original lenghts 
  maxDD <- sapply(ll,FUN = function(x) max(window(DD,start=index(DD)[sumas[x]],end=index(DD)[sumas[x+1]-1])))
  data.frame(start=index(DD)[sumas[ll]],end=index(DD)[sumas[ll+1]-1], length=(index(DD)[sumas[ll+1]-1]-index(DD)[sumas[ll]])+1, maxDD)
}
```

I've also corrected a problem that prevented me from getting an ordered answer because I was writting index(DD[]) instead of index(DD)[]

Now it seems to work but I'm not sure.

to Joshua:
At the beginning my data was zoo with chron index
Now I've transformed it to xts with posixct index,

```
"2010-01-11 18:00:00" 9338.37028375963
"2010-01-11 18:15:00" 8086.45780960387
"2010-01-11 18:30:00" 7762.75622449016
"2010-01-11 18:45:00" 8358.3609798313
"2010-01-11 19:00:00" 8598.69695502083
"2010-01-11 19:15:00" 8568.56256494502
"2010-01-11 19:30:00" 8488.4281748692
...
```

still doesn't work with performanceAnalytics, though I can graph it and make any calculations by my own.
Drawdown(myData) gives a xts series with all its data values NaN.
I've been looking at findDrawdown code and it's different to mine because it measures relative drawdowns instead of absolute drawdowns.

Anyway, I hope my script could be useful to someone.

Comment: The PerformanceAnalytics package is used by many professionals around the world, so I would strongly encourage you to investigate what's wrong with your data that prevents it from working with PerformanceAnalytics... rather than re-inventing the wheel and asking others to fix your work.

Comment: @Joshua, Harsh. Stop reading Dirk's posts, I think it's getting to you :P

Comment: With performanceAnalytics I get " The data cannot be converted into a time series" if I use my data as zoo or xts , chron or POSIXct.  I've been googling and many people has the same problem.  In fact performanceAnalytics doesn't work for me even with its own examples.

Comment: @user425895 I receive 3 results (one is this question) when I search for "The data cannot be converted into a time series".  How do you find "many people (with) the same problem"?  Which PerformanceAnalytics function are you trying to use?  What do your data look like?

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the older function `maxdrawdown` from the [tseries](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tseries) package. Here is an example from its manual page:

```
mxdrwdR> # Realistic example
mxdrwdR> data(EuStockMarkets)

mxdrwdR> dax <- log(EuStockMarkets[,"DAX"])

mxdrwdR> mdd <- maxdrawdown(dax)

mxdrwdR> mdd
$maxdrawdown
[1] 0.25647

$from
[1] 236

$to
[1] 331
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is  that this one just gives me one drawdown without dates. I've tried to convert its output to dates but it's not the same than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about max drawdowns, but here are some thoughts on your code.

---

It isn't entirely clear what form the input `DD` takes.  You likely want some input checking to make sure that it is correctly formed.

---

```
rr <- rle(coredata(sign(DD)))
```

Unless you've overloaded this function, `sign` returns a numeric vector (containing -1s, 0s and 1s).  Did you mean `sign(coredata(DD))`?

---

```
lens[rr$value == FALSE] <- 0
```

You define the variable `lens` but then go back to using `rr$length` later.

---

```
rr$value == FALSE
```

Use `!rr$value` instead; it's clearer.

---

```
ll <- head(order(rr$length, decreasing=TRUE),5)
```

I don't know how central this is to the method but you might want to allow the user to input how many of the longest runs are used into the function rather than hardcoding it to be 5.

---

Code is easier to read when you are consistent with where you put spaces.  Personally, I prefer a space after a comma and spaces before and after operators.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestions. I've modified the code on the main post.

Comment: My input is DD <- cummax(equity)-equity, thus is always equal or greater than zero. sign(DD) will be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

The functions in PerformanceAnalytics only fail when using chron as the index.  I've suggested to you before that you should not rely on chron for your zoo/xts index values.

The error gives you a hint why it doesn't work: "Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'".  chron does not use standard date formats, hence the error.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(chron)

getSymbols("SPY")
r <- na.omit(ROC(Cl(SPY)))
# xts object with 'Date' index
str(SPY)
table.Drawdowns(r)
table.Drawdowns(as.zoo(r))
# convert index to chron
index(r) <- as.chron(index(r))
table.Drawdowns(r)          # fails
table.Drawdowns(as.zoo(r))  # fails
# convert index to POSIXct
index(r) <- as.POSIXct(index(r))
table.Drawdowns(r)
table.Drawdowns(as.zoo(r))
```

Comment: I get:   Error in if (thisSign == priorSign) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE is necessary.  My data is just  datetime and the value of the drawdown

Comment: @user425895: you have missing values in your return series.  Notice how I called `na.omit` when creating `r`.

Comment: In that post I also said that performanceAnalytics didn't work me. That's why I made the script